# Subset a string

Tags: matlab

It's easy to subset a *character vector*:

```matlab
>> c = 'hello world';
>> c(1:5)

ans =

    'hello'
```

But that doesn't work for *strings*:

```matlab
>> s = "hello world";
>> s(1:5)
Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).
```

How do I subset a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`extractBetween`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/extractbetween.html) function:

```matlab
>> s = "hello world";
>> extractBetween(s, 1, 5)

ans = 

    "hello"
```

Comment: As usual in Matlab, the string is actually a 1x1 array of strings. You can also index into that array with `{1}`, which gives the first string's "contents" as a character vector (as if the string array were a cell array of char vectors). And then you can chain `()`-indexing: `s{1}(1:5)`. The result, however, is a char vector, not a string